# Creating Framework for iOS using external dependencies (pods)

Tags: swift, xcode, dependencies, frameworks, xcframework

My goal is to create a framework that I will ship to our clients to use our code to achieve some functionality done by our library.

I had searched a lot to make a library using other dependencies as Alamofire or Google MLKit pods, but could not find a full tutorial on how to work on it.

Is it possible to do a library (framework) that depends on other dependencies? And is there a good tutorial to follow?

Comment: It's possible, but it's really painful: issues with module stability, custom build scripts people who use your framework need to run, problems with debugging and so on. In short - I don't recommend. Instead, make those modules "required" for your POD, but not included with it. Especially since they are 3rd-party. That way your integrators will need to include them, but you won't need to have all the complications with static frameworks (which is the only way to go about it) within your framework

Comment: Thank you for replying, you really help me know what may I face in the future. Is there any recommended article to start creating my framework?